# Angular 5 error when add global CSS file

Tags: javascript, css, angular, webpack, webpack-style-loader

When I add global CSS file to Angular project or even add some style to styles.css, I get Error from Webpack.

> ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"import":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/style.css
>   Module build failed: Syntax Error
>
> (9:2) Unknown word
>
> 7 |     width: 100px;   8 |     height: 100px;
>
> -> 9 | }​

No matter how I add file:
angular-cli.json

```
      "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "./assets/style.css"
  ],
```

Or import in styles.css.
Can someone help me?

My css file content.

```
.center-message{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: -50px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
```

}​

Comment: can post your css your importing ?
looks like an error in your css files

Comment: Problem was in your .css file.

Comment: @ShakeerHussain  Ok. Look at my css file ther is only one class

Comment: @NadhirFalta Look at my css file

Comment: @ЮлийЩербак are you using webpack or angular-cli ?

Comment: @NadhirFalta angular-cli 1.6.4

Comment: @ЮлийЩербак the css you posted is that inside "./assets/style.css" or "style.css" ?

Comment: @NadhirFalta  "./assets/style.css"  Even if i add some css code to standart styles.css i get the same error

Comment: Have you tried to put `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">` in your index.html instead of what you are doing?

Comment: @ЮлийЩербак it's very weird man!! I don't see anything wrong with it.  Did What if you empty both files and keep them completely empty, will still get errors ?  Also, are you using sass ?

Comment: @Nadhir Falta No i did not get error when they are empty, and i not use sass. But what interesting bootstrap and material css are imported and work fine.

Comment: @ЮлийЩербак Alright!! can you take a screenshot of the content of both files?? the complete style code inside both of them ? also make sure the path and naming is correct

Comment: @Yazan Mehrez if i do it webpack will did not watch my css file and i always must recompile my app??? Or not?

Comment: @Nadhir Fakta import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
All my code in styles.css. and all code of style.css at the top. All path are corect.